# How to Cron Job Logs in Sentry laravel

Tags: php, laravel, performance, laravel-5, sentry

I need to cron job log in sentry using laravel

Call sentry log method:

```
$this->sentryCronJobLog([
                'affected_rows'=> $affectedRows,
                'status' => 'success'
            ]);
```

this method to logged in sentry:

```
public function sentryCronJobLog($data){
        if (app()->bound('sentry')) {   
            \Sentry\configureScope(function (Scope $scope)use ($data): void {
                $scope->setTag('status', $data['status']);
                $scope->setTag('affected_rows', $data['affected_rows']);
                $scope->setTag('time',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d h:i a'));  
            });
        }
    }
```

In this way, I have unable to create a log in sentry Performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add one line into sentryCronJobLog() function

```
 $transactionContext = new \Sentry\Tracing\TransactionContext();
 $transactionContext->setName('Cron job -'.$data['command_name']);
 $transactionContext->setOp('command.run');
 $transaction = \Sentry\startTransaction($transactionContext);

 $transaction->finish();
```

It's work for me

```
public function sentryCronJobLog($data){
        if (app()->bound('sentry')) {   
            \Sentry\configureScope(function (Scope $scope)use ($data): void {
                $scope->setTag('status', $data['status']);
                $scope->setTag('affected_rows', $data['affected_rows']);
                $scope->setTag('time',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d h:i a'));
                
                $transactionContext = new \Sentry\Tracing\TransactionContext();
                $transactionContext->setName('Cron job - .$data['command_name']);
                $transactionContext->setOp('command.run');
                $transaction = \Sentry\startTransaction($transactionContext);

                $transaction->finish();
            });
        }
    }
```